# Should i use Smarfox Server for flash or can i build my mini java server

Tags: java, flash

is it possible for me to build a server in java so that i can let my different flash clients communicate with each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any HTTP server of your choice.
If you want functions like data pushing, you might want to try [Blaze DS](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/blazeds/BlazeDS/).

> BlazeDS is the server-based Java remoting and web messaging technology that enables developers to easily connect to back-end distributed data and push data in real-time to Adobe Flex and Adobe AIR™ applications for more responsive rich Internet application (RIA) experiences.

The buzzwords aside, it has good support for data pushing features and is tuned for interacting with Flex applications.

Answer (score 1):

You could write your own server using [Netty](http://jboss.org/netty) if you wished.

Comment: i dint mean that... actually am a game programmer and i find this smartfox server a bit awkward...coming from a java bg..i find flash scripting easy...so i am thinking of not a big and large server like netty using jboss or something... wat i mean is ....isnt a small class file enough for the different flash clients to communicate ....or am i thinking wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Dont think you understand the SmartfoxServer at all.
Would suggest you read the [SmartfoxServer documentation](http://www.smartfoxserver.com/docs/) completely first.
Last but not the least, Completely disagree with the statement SmartfoxServer being "a bit awkward"

P.S: Very interesting.
Smartfox Server programmer at Cochin?

Comment: yes.... njan ivide kalamasseryil oru software companyeela....where are u?